# eclipse egit some files won't commit to github

Tags: eclipse, github

I have a github repository and it is integrated into eclipse.  I sometimes create files in other text editors, then refresh my project and then left click the project to get >Team>Commit.  This usually gets every file.  Unfortunately, I have several files that failed to commit this way.  I don't see them on github and I can see the following when I do Team Synchronizing.

[image]

There is nothing I can do to get these files to commit to github.  Can anyone see why?  These is no error message or warning or anything.  When I go to commit these files, they don't appear in the window that shows everything that needs to be commited (ie is new or has changes).

Comment: I don't know the Eclipse version, but... Is there a .gitignore file in the root folder of the git project? What is its content? Have you tried command-line git? I think your files may be already committed, just not pushed to Github. Git is not Github.

Comment: Hi, I looked at my gitignore and it doesn't contain anything that would relate to these files.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse EGit, the preferred way to create commits is by using the [Staging View](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Git_Staging_View). It shows a clear view of what files are staged and ready to commit and what changed files are not. It supports drag-and-drop to move files from un-staged to staged, as well as commit and commit+push directly in the view.

Open the Staging View and see if those files are in the Unstaged section. If so, drag them to Staged and then commit.